# How can I modify the label_feats_from_corpus function in order to take a tagged corpus in the form of a tuple (word, tag) as a feature-detector?

Tags: python, nltk

I want to modify the label_feats_from_corpus function in order to take a tagged corpus in the form of a tuple (word, tag) as a feature-detector. Instead of taking bag-of-words or bag-of-bigram-words as features, I want to take bag-of-tagged-words to test the accuracy of the classifier in this case.

Comment: it is ok to provide more details of what you can do and what you want to get.\

Comment: are you saying that instead of using `Bag-of-Words (BoW)` as features, you want to use `Bag-of-Tags`? At least for CRF++, you can use `[x,1]` to represent tag features instead of `[x,0]` for word features.